# Dynamic Allocating memory on GPU

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to dynamically allocate memory on a GPU's Global memory inside the Kernel?
i don't know how big will my answer be, therefore i need a way to allocate memory for each part of the answer. CUDA 4.0 alloww us to use the RAM... is it a good idea or will it reduce the speed??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it is possible to use malloc inside a kernel. check the following which is taken from nvidia cuda guide:

```
__global__ void mallocTest() 
{ 
  char* ptr = (char*)malloc(123); 
  printf(“Thread %d got pointer: %p\n”, threadIdx.x, ptr); 
  free(ptr); 
} 
void main() 
{ 
  cudaThreadSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 128*1024*1024); 
  mallocTest<<<1, 5>>>(); 
  cudaThreadSynchronize(); 
} 

will output: 
Thread 0 got pointer: 00057020 
Thread 1 got pointer: 0005708c 
Thread 2 got pointer: 000570f8 
Thread 3 got pointer: 00057164
```

Comment: @ scatman: I guess the memory allocated will be on the device once you call malloc within a kernel... Am I right?

Comment: Since a cpu cannot malloc as fast as 2048 cores of gtx980, I suspect it allocates on gpu. otherwise it would be just for integrated gpus not discrete.

Answer (score 1):

From CUDA 4.0 you will be able to use `new` and `delete` operators from c++ instead of `malloc` and `free` from c.